# I have a race game. How would I structure my code?

Tags: lua, roblox

Suppose a variable
`CoinsObtainedByStunts = 0`

When a player performs a backflip with their car and lands on the 4 wheels.
`CoinsObtainedBystunts = CoinsObtainedByStunts + 10`

how would I define what a backflip is?

I already have a variable called IsJumping that becomes true when raycasts can determine that the car is in the air and thus "Jumping"

So I'd use the IsJumping to verify if the car is able to perform a backflip.

But how would I define
`function HasPerformedBackflip()` ?

how do I structure it in the most tidy way possible? What variables do I use? How have other race games done it?

Maybe I can call it as soon as the IsJUmping = true and then run coroutines that will be like

```
startingcartrotation = 0
local cartrotated = 0
while IsJumping do
cartrotated = cartrotated + getcartrotation
wait()
end
if cartrotated = startingcartrotation then
return true
```

please help?

Comment: post code. you cannot ask how to implement a game. this is way to broad. please read [ask]

Comment: Try to implement something. If it works, it works. If it doesn't work correctly or fast enough then you have better starting point for asking a question. You are asking correct questions here, but you should point them at yourself. Think about "how do I define what a backflip is" and "how do I represent and store a state of an ongoing backflip". Then answer them in your code. It can be naive, it can be wrong; it doesn't matter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dot products - this is your answer.

I'm going to write code in the context of Roblox and using the language Lua but you can easily translate this to Unity or something else.

The idea is, you would attach a 'Root' part to your vehicle whose **LookVector** (Z-axis in Roblox's case) will be facing **down** when the vehicle is upright.

On the physics step, I'm going to calculate the dot product of the world's **UpVector** (0, 1, 0) and the root's **LookVector**, using this, we will be able to tell if the vehicle is in the process of doing a back-flip and when it has finished doing it's back-flip.

```
local upVector = Vector3.new(0, 1, 0)
local lastDirection = "Down"

local function onBackflip()
    print("+10 Coins!")
end

local function onPhysicsStep()
    local lookVector = Root.CFrame.LookVector
    local dotProduct = lookVector:Dot(upVector)

    if (dotProduct < 0) then
        --// Facing downwards
        if (lastDirection == "Up") then
           onBackflip()
        end
        
        lastDirection = "Down"
    elseif (dotProduct > .8) then
        --// In the process of a back-flip
        lastDirection = "Up"
    end
end
```

Result: https://gyazo.com/647e3e59418831ffb1a5e448778ec90f